# Pull bulleted list from MySQL in php

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to produce a bulleted list from text field in MySQL - I have the bullets in the DB field : I'm pulling data into the array $products, I need the string in array to be formatted as a bullet list in the products $Keyfindings2 results

```
<?php

/* This controller renders the category pages */

class CategoryController{
    public function handleRequest(){
    $cat = Category::find(array('id'=>$_GET['category']));

    if(empty($cat)){
        throw new Exception("There is no such category!");
    }

    // Fetch all the categories:
    $categories = Category::find();

    // Fetch all the products in this category:
    $products = Product::find(array('category'=>$_GET['category']));

    // $categories and $products are both arrays with objects


    $Keyfindings2 = explode('•', $products);
            echo "<ul style=\' list-style-type:upper-roman;\'>\n";

                foreach( $Keyfindings2 as $item )
                    {
                        echo "<li>$item</li><br />\n";
                    }
                        echo "</ul>";


    render('category',array(
        'title'         => 'Browsing '.$cat[0]->name,
        'categories'    => $categories,
        'products'      => $Keyfindings2

    ));     
    }
}


?>
```

[image]

UPDATE: now getting 'undefined variable' in other part of code on line 1:

```
<li <?php echo ($active == $category->id ? 'data-theme="a"' : '') ?>>
<a href="?category=<?php echo $category->id?>" data-transition="fade">
<?php echo $category->name ?>
<span class="ui-li-count"><?php echo $category->contains?></span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Maybe it's only me but I have no idea what your problem is. You post is composed of: 1 phrase, 30/40 lines of code and a screenshot. I doubt anyone can help you with this. To have better chances of getting answers, please consider doing like so: 1/ your initial state, eg. "I have this data"; 2/ what you're expecting, "I want my data to be displayed coma separated"; 3/ what you actually have, "My data is displayed semi-colon separated"

Comment: Reworded question to further explain

Comment: Ok it's still unclear, but I think I'm getting it. In your database you have a field containing something like `* foo * bar * baz` (I'm using `*` as list bullet, as you still didn't provided the data you have so I don't know what you have for real) and you want to operate that string so you have a php array, correct?

Comment: Correct : use the * as a delimiter and produce the li list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is quite simple: you are using `explode` on the wrong thing.

If your code/comments is right `$products` is an array and you `explode` it. You probably have your PHP error level too low because this produce a PHP warning: `PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in php shell code on line 1`

So from there 2 solutions: either `$products` is an array of strings and you can do

```
function myExplode($product) {
    return explode('•', $product);
}
$Keyfindings2 = array_map('myExplode', $products);
```

or `$products` is an array of objects (as your code comment suggests) and you go with:

```
function myExplode($product) {
    // well actual the name of the field or method to call really depends on your
    // code and there is no way we can tell it with what we have on your post
    // so consider this an example
    return explode('•', $product->productFieldContainingList);
}
$Keyfindings2 = array_map('myExplode', $products);
```

With either solution the goal is the same: to apply `explode` on the correct data, not on an array containing that data.

Comment: Can you show a little more of where this go's ? - I think the echoed results need to be stored in the $Keyfindings2 to populate the products results

Comment: It's a replacement for the `$Keyfindings2 = explode('•', $products);` line.

Comment: I'm getting 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home/a8542612/public_html/includes/controllers/category.controller.php on return explode line

Comment: My bad, I forgot the `$` in the function's argument, edited accordingly

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: Oh that's why. PHP 5.2 don't have lambda functions, so you'd have to extract the lambda into a named function. I will update my answer. FYI PHP 5.2 is reaaaaaaally old now and not supported anymore. You should consider an upgrade :)

Comment: Thanks so much, sorry for all the questions

Comment: You're welcome. If this helped you, please consider marking at this question's answer :)

Comment: Marked answer. But see my update above, getting error in other part of code project.